# Call a .php file inside html using Javascript

Tags: php, html

I want to call a php file inside my html file. I am using a button to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" value="click on me!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="maindiv">
        <?php include 'tdesignAPI/new_applit.php'; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I look at the browser, there is nothing happening. I look at the developer console and I found that it auto commented the php script. Please take a look.

[image]

Why does it so? How can I use my html file to **PROPERLY** call my php?

Comment: Are you executing the file on a server or locally? Is the file extension `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: i have an index.html file that calls index.php file locally.

Comment: PHP requires a web server to execute. See [this link](https://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/running-php-files/).

Comment: your html file should be saved with .php extension and also web server required .

Comment: Can you please check the file encoding of your html and php file?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an .htaccess file and add the ff.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

place it at where your html file.
then your code will work

Answer (score 0):

**Your `php` page/code not executed by server**

There is many possibilities behind this the main are

1.) your open/execute page directly from directory i.e "d:\pages\yourpage.html"

2.) if your page has different extension then php  you need to create `htaccess` file in same directory and write

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`